# add jquery scroll / click functions

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

can someone please show me how to properly add these two functions together? I want to be able to click the .nav only if its top: value is below/equal to -70px. It basically works fine now, but if the user is on the top of the screen I don't want them to be able to close the .nav, until the scroll function has moved it -70px then make click function active. Thanks!!

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var topMove = -1 * (620 * $(this).scrollTop() / $('body').height());
    console.log(topMove);
    if(topMove >= -70) {
        $('.nav').css({ top: Math.max(topMove) });
    }
});

$('.nav').click(function () {
    if (!$('.nav').hasClass('clicked')) {
        $(".nav").stop().animate({ top: "0px" }, 750);
        $('.nav').addClass('clicked');
    } 
    else if ($('.nav').hasClass('clicked')) {
        $(".nav").stop().animate({ top: "-60px" }, 750);
        $('.nav').removeClass('clicked');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UXZ4E/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to the top of your click function ([jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/VrScF/)):

```
if($(document).scrollTop() <= 70) return false;
```

It basically just stops the function of the browser is not scrolled down at least 70 pixels.